# Get attr value in PHP $_POST

Tags: php, get, attr

I have a simple form. Need get additional attr value on POST PHP.

**This is my form:**

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" action="post_form.php">
     <input type="text" name="user_name" />
     <input type="text" name="user_email" data-required="true" />
</form>
```

**PHP post:**

```
extract($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $input_name  = $key;
    $input_value = $value;        
    //How to get value of data-required?
    $attr_value = ?????
}
```

Comment: 1. `extract($_POST);` just why ??

Comment: extract($_POST) is recovery all inputs.

Comment: Without Javascript...you can't. You would need to have javascript serialize that attribute and then have javascript either make an ajax request or put that value into a hidden input.

Comment: Why don't you just create a hidden input field and have its value equal to the value of `data-required`?

Comment: Don't is possible without use JavaScript?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need `data-required` data?

Comment: Because some fields will need different information in `data-required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that attribute directly from PHP. You will need to javascript to read that attribute on form submit and serialize it into your POST data and then make an ajax request or have javascript write the value into a hidden input.

The following is a simple mock up of what I mean using a hidden input

**HTML**

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" action="post_form.php">

     <input type="text" name="user_name" />

     <input type="text" name="user_email" data-required="true" id="useremail" />

     <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" id="hiddeninput" />

</form>
```

**Javascript** (using jQuery)

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#hiddeninput").val($("#useremail").data("required")); //set value of hidden input
});
```

At this point, the hidden input's value is the value of the `data-required` attribute. You will then be able to read the hidden input's value in PHP